# Can you kill all the dummies in freeplay mode and be the only crewmate left standing?

Tags: among-us

I don't know if this is possible but i figured out a way to do this.

1. Become imposter and kill every dummy but the last two
2. Change to Crewmate, and report a body. Hopefully a dummy gets voted out
3. Call an emergency meeting and try to vote out the last dummy

I tried doing this a bunch of times but I always get voted out on step 3 :( Is there some kind of code that prevents the last dummy from being voted out

Comment: Hello. Not an answer but what would be the purpose of that ? In among us, if the  number of Imposters = the number of Crewmates, the Imposters automatically win. So, in your setup,  the game would automatically end ?

Comment: The freeplay mode is actually for just for trying out the game.The only player is you and a bunch of dummy crewmates.Initially there are zero imposters.You can turn yourself into an imposter in the settings to practice killing the crewmates,the game resets if there is only 1 dummy left.I was wondering if you could eject that last dummy and be alone in the map.Of course there is no purpose in doing that,just wanna know if that state is achieveable

Comment: Number of imposters =/= Number of crewmates if you turn back into a crewmate on step 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few tries I managed to do it, it's just pure luck to do it though.

For those of us wondering, you can still do tasks and win that way as crewmate, this will respawn all the dummies. (Although, a simpler way would be to just become Impostor again and respawn them.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible :D i made it after like the 100th try

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/295913)

Comment: @DavidYell: But it does, and he is the author...

Comment: Ah, I missed that in Review. Apologies